# how to open unicode encoded URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code works as expected:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
with urlopen('https://mr.wikipedia.org/s/4jp4') as f:
    f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

But similar code returns an error. Both the URL's point to the same wiki article.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
with urlopen('https://mr.wikipedia.org/wiki/किशोरावस्था') as f:
    f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   10-20: ordinal not in range(128)

I need to use python built-in modules and therefore can not use requests module.

---

This works. But in my case the URL is part of an API and I do not know which word to quote. Is there more general solution like requests?

```
from urllib.parse   import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://mr.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + quote("किशोरावस्था")
content = urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: this worked fine with requests

Comment: I tried `res = requests.get('https://mr.wikipedia.org/wiki/किशोरावस्था') res.content.decode('utf8')`

Comment: The URL is not strictly speaking Unicode-encoded, because Unicode is not an encoding. The page (or the response) is "utf-8" encoded (or should be).

Comment: Provide the full traceback. It gives us more useful information than you think.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: python 3.7 shows the error

Comment: There is also an open issue for this - https://bugs.python.org/issue3991

Comment: This edit " But in my case the URL is part of an API and I do not know which word to quote. Is there more general solution like requests" should be a new question I think.

Comment: ?? Why not "everything after the final /"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url is the error creator here. Try:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
with urlopen('https://mr.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+urllib.parse.quote('किशोरावस्था')) as f:
    f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: lol ok the question closed with the right answer. I found this answer before that. Sorry if this was late